# Custom session in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I am trying to set session in theme so I have added code in `header.php` file of theme folder. When I set session, it works but after refresh the page, the session is destroyed. I have added `_session` in `wp_unregister_GLOBALS()` function which is in `load.php` file. I don't know what I am doing wrong. My code is as follows:

```
session_start();

if ($_SESSION['usersubdomain']) {
    echo "Session Set " . $_SESSION['usersubdomain'];
}
else
{
    echo "Session is not Set ";
    $_SESSION['usersubdomain'] = "Check Session";
}
```

Each and every time it echos "session is not set".

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that your code is checking if the value of `$_SESSION['usersubdomain']` is `true`.

What you need to do is to check if `$_SESSION['usersubdomain']` is set.
Please try the code below:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['usersubdomain']) AND !empty($_SESSION['usersubdomain'])){
  echo "Session Set ".$_SESSION['usersubdomain'];
}
else{
  echo "Session is not Set ";
  $_SESSION['usersubdomain']="Check Session";
}
```

EDIT: included to check if `!empty($_SESSION['usersubdomain'])`